# Loading modules along with data using lazy loading resulting in infinite loop

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I am having an issue with lazy loading a module when passing data. It is resulting in infinite loop.
Here is a detailed explanation :

**Modules**

- IndexModule (contains the home page with basic info along with a navbar)
- AuthenticationModule (contains login and signup page)

In IndexModule **index-routing.module.ts** :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndexPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => AuthenticationModule,
    data: {
     page: 'login'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    loadChildren: () => AuthenticationModule,
    data: {
      page: 'signup'
    }
  }
];
```

I am using the login/signup button on navbar present in IndexModule to load login/signup page in AuthenticationModule with data attribute to tell me which page I need to redirect to in AuthenticationModule.

My AuthenticationModule **authentication.module.ts** file looks like this:

```
export class AuthenticationModule {

  pageToRedirect: String;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {

    this.router.events.subscribe(data => {
      if (data instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        this.pageToRedirect = data.state.root.firstChild.data.page;
        if (this.pageToRedirect === 'login') {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
          console.log('Login');
        } else if (this.pageToRedirect === 'signup') {
          this.router.navigate(['signup']);
          console.log('Signup');
        }
      }
    });: 

  }

}
```

Here I subscribe to the observable data and check if the page is 'login' or 'signup' and navigate accordingly.
But doing so is resulting in an infinite loop.

Either console.log('login') or console.log('signup') keeps running indefinitely.
Can anyone please tell me what mistake I am making here and if there is a workaround to the approach I am using.

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with a lock:

```
export class AuthenticationModule {

  pageToRedirect: String;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {

     this.router.events.subscribe(data => {
       if (data instanceof RoutesRecognized) {

          // enter only if this.pageToRedirect is undefined
          if(!this.pageToRedirect){
              this.pageToRedirect = data.state.root.firstChild.data.page;

              if (this.pageToRedirect === 'login') {
                 this.router.navigate(['login']);
                 console.log('Login');
              } else if (this.pageToRedirect === 'signup') {
                 this.router.navigate(['signup']);
                 console.log('Signup');
             }

          }

       }
     });

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I also wanted to know why is this code running infinite loop. Do you happen to have any idea about this ?

Comment: If this answer helped you I'd appreciate you to mark it as solution.

Comment: This is because you initially subscribe to the router.events "this.router.events.subscribe(data => {})" and this event is triggered again as soon as one of your "route.navigate()" calls takes place inside the subscription. This event is fired much faster than or at least as fast as the routing action to the target page. That's why you enter the subscription again and with it the same code repetitively.

Comment: Thanks. Got it :)

Comment: Don't mention it. ;)